# GCM with sample android testapp for push notification

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to learn how to use the `GCM` by going over their step by step guild. I get to the point of registering but it never actually does the registration part of the project. I have the configuration file in the project and I am using this website to test for push notification http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/gcm.html
So this is what it is giving me in the logcat:

```
02-18 14:07:42.866 32402-32402/com.example.mmillar.gcmpushnotificationtest D/Main Activity: Started
02-18 14:07:42.867 32402-32402/com.example.mmillar.gcmpushnotificationtest D/Checking PlayService: Started
02-18 14:07:42.868 32402-32402/com.example.mmillar.gcmpushnotificationtest D/Cheking player Service: true
02-18 14:07:42.868 32402-32402/com.example.mmillar.gcmpushnotificationtest D/Starting service:: Intent { cmp=com.example.mmillar.gcmpushnotificationtest/.Registration }
02-18 14:07:42.877 32402-32432/com.example.mmillar.gcmpushnotificationtest D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
02-18 14:07:42.949 32402-32432/com.example.mmillar.gcmpushnotificationtest I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-18 14:07:43.008 32402-32432/com.example.mmillar.gcmpushnotificationtest W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-18 14:07:43.008 32402-32432/com.example.mmillar.gcmpushnotificationtest W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad79f100, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-18 14:07:45.679 32402-32407/com.example.mmillar.gcmpushnotificationtest W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.876ms
02-18 14:07:53.143 32402-32429/com.example.mmillar.gcmpushnotificationtest I/GMPM: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
02-18 14:08:33.167 32402-32411/com.example.mmillar.gcmpushnotificationtest W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.121ms
02-18 14:10:19.493 32402-32407/com.example.mmillar.gcmpushnotificationtest W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.036ms
02-18 14:11:15.635 32402-32407/com.example.mmillar.gcmpushnotificationtest W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.898ms
```

As it shows it get down to the start(intent0 part of the `onCreate` method. But it never reaches to the Register class at all. I am a bit stumped on what I am doing wrong here. Any help will be appreciated.

here is the main activity code that starts the app

```
public class GCMMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
    private ProgressBar mRegistrationProgressBar;
    private TextView mInformationTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gcmmain);
        Log.d("Main Activity", "Started");

        mRegistrationProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.registrationProgressBar);
        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("Main Activity: ", "onReceive Method");
                mRegistrationProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                boolean sentToken = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Preferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);
                if (sentToken) {
                    mInformationTextView.setText("Token retrieved and sent to server! You can now use gcmsender to\n" +
                            "        send downstream messages to this app");
                } else {
                    mInformationTextView.setText("An error occurred while either fetching the InstanceID token,\n" +
                            "sending the fetched token to the server or subscribing to the PubSub topic. ");
                }
            }
        };
        mInformationTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.informationTextView);

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            Log.d("Checking PlayService", "Started");
            Boolean check = checkPlayServices();
            Log.d("Cheking player Service ", check.toString());
            // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Registration.class);
            //this should call the registration code
            Log.d("Starting service: ", intent.toString());
            startService(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Preferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

  //deos the device support google play?
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                        .show();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is the registration class

```
public class Registration  extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
    private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};
    private final String SENDERID = "630172590481";

    public Registration() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Registration Class: ", "onHandleIntent mehtod");
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        //Register for the gcm
        try {

            // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
            // are local.
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);

            //this is using the google configuration file crated at their website
            //https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            /*used to hardcode the Sender ID
            String token = instanceID.getToken(SENDERID),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
                    */
            Log.d(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

            sendRegistrationToServer(token);

            // Subscribe to topic channels
            subscribeTopics(token);

            // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
            // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
            // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Preferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
            // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
            // update at a later time.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Preferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Preferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }

    /**
     * Persist registration to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }

    //Subscribe to any GCM topics of interest, as defined by the TOPICS constant.
    private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
        GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
        for (String topic : TOPICS) {
            pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not implement the sendRegistrationToServer(String token) method

Comment: Disclaimer:- I wrote this tutorial. You can have a look at it -http://inducesmile.com/android/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-mysql-and-okhttp-square-open-source/

Comment: I see thanks I will run though your tutorial and give that a shot thank you. From what I see by briefly looking over your tutorial it great.

Comment: Thank you @Nolly J that works perfectly and its really well done to. I like the OKHttp thing it seams a little faster than the URLConnectiion stuff and way easier to work with than the URL one.